# match a string not followed by another (preg_match negative look aheads)

Tags: php, preg-match

I have to select rows that contain the word `one` and not `another`. The rows come form some json string, like those:

```
{"Name" : "one", "LastError" : "No error", "ID" : 1000 , "Comment" : "no comment"} //YES
{"Name" : "one", "LastError" : "No error", "ID" : 1000 , "Comment" : "another"} //NO because there is 'one' and 'another'
```

I am using php and preg_match.

I'am trying to use someting like:

```
if (preg_match('/one.*(?!another)/i',$row_string) > 0)
{
  //no draw
}
else
{
  //Draw something
}
```

It seems that the look ahead doesn't do anything.

Comment: It is quite a masochistic solution. Why don't you use `json_decode` instead?

Comment: No, is not. Here I have posted 4 fields, but in the real software I have about 20 field. If I use json_decode, i have to call 20 times preg_match, and I have to relate each call to each other (foreward and backward eventually). The user wants a search on the entire record, so I choose to use a json_encode to obtain a string (I already have an object).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex

```
/one.*(?!another)/
```

means *match the string `one` followed by any number of characters, and the string after `.*` must not match `another`*.

`.*` will basically match up to the end of the string, so it isn't followed by `another`.

What you actually want is to match the string `one` followed by any number of characters, and each of them must not be followed by `another`.

**This one works:**

```
/one(.(?!another))*$/
```

The `$` makes sure that the assertion is tested against every character following `one`.

To make sure that even `one` itself isn't preceded by `another`, we have to add the assertion just after `one` too:

```
/one(?!another)(.(?!another))*$/
```

Comment: This will still match a string where 'another' precedes 'one'. That may be ok for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`one` is only in `Name`? If so, `json_decode($json, true)`.